# Azure AD B2C with Angular4 and WebAPI Core2 token validation issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt, identity, azure-ad-b2c, .net-core-2.0

Doesn't seem Azure documentation can give a clear example hot to do it right.

There are Angular4 (WebApp) and WebAPI Core 2.0 back-end.Two application configured in Azure B2C. WebApp has WebAPI app in its API access.

Web app gets redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize. There, credentials provided and then AAD B2C calls back WebApp page with access_token, token_type, expires_in, id_token url parameters.

Then, WebApp makes a request to a protected endpoint of the back-end with access_token in Authorization header. MessageReceivedAsync is called when request hits the back-end and goes all the way through validating the token.

However, when process exits the method next step it goes into is AuthenticationFailed with error.

```
"IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid': 'Base64_kid', 
token: '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"Base64_kid"}.{"iss":"number of claims"}'."
```

My understanding that Audience is the WebAPI application id. I have only a SingIn/Up policy.

What am I missing here to complete jwt manual validation w/o errors? Another question, when claimsPrincipal is created when token validated, how does it go into request context to be able to access protected endpoint?

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/",
                Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Tenant"], Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Policy"]);
            options.Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:ClientId"];
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                OnMessageReceived = MessageReceivedAsync,
                OnChallenge = Challenge,
                OnTokenValidated = TokenValidated
            };
        });

    ...
}
private Task MessageReceivedAsync(MessageReceivedContext arg)
{
    string jwtToken = null;

    var aadInstance = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:AADInstance"];
    var tenant = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Tenant"];
    var audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Audience"];
    var policy = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Policy"];
    var authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

    string _issuer = string.Empty;
    List<SecurityKey> _signingTokens = null;
    var authHeader = arg.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

    // 7 = (Bearer + " ").Length
    var token = authHeader.ToString().Substring(7);
    try
    {
        string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = string.Format("{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}", authority, policy);
        var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, 
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = null;
        var openIdConfigTask = Task.Run(async () => {
            config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
        });
        openIdConfigTask.Wait();

        _issuer = config.Issuer;
        _signingTokens = config.SigningKeys.ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = audience,
        ValidIssuer = _issuer,
        IssuerSigningKeys = _signingTokens
    };
    var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
    //Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal; ?
    //var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, arg.Scheme.Name); ?
    //arg.HttpContext.User = claimsPrincipal; ?

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem.  Had to set the `MetadataAddress` property manually.  See the duplicate SO post the reason and [this code sample](https://github.com/spottedmahn/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal/blob/b543ccbedbb4a83e1809351b38cb34afc4f02c62/StartupAuth.cs#L24)

Comment: Both options worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options.Audience` property is correct (i.e. the application identifier for the Web API application) but the JWT bearer authentication middleware is downloading the wrong signing keys because you don't seem to be setting the `options.Authority` property to the right value.

It must include the Azure AD B2C policy.

You should be setting it to:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/v2.0/'`

such as:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Tenant"]}/{Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ida:Policy"]}/v2.0/`.

As result of the token validation, the `HttpContext.User` object contains the claims from the token, so you can control access for example via scopes.